# VideoView force close on Micromax Canvas magnus

Tags: android, android-videoview

Why `VideoView` force closes on Micromax Canvas magnus ?

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; regionStart=0;
>   regionLength=-1 at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
>   at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464) at
>   android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:407) at
>   android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:730) at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:606) at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88) at
>   android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183) at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:692)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579) at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548) at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: no, i have got issue when play video on splash screen.

Comment: i have found a solution other way round ! check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31942841/4646227