# Which device is perfectly suitable for checking android apps at development?

Tags: android, emulation

I want to check my developing application in android device. But i have ([VideoView force close on Micromax Canvas magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364444/videoview-force-close-on-micromax-canvas-magnus), [java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while playing video in videoView : Android v 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865340/java-lang-stringindexoutofboundsexception-while-playing-video-in-videoview-and/31942841#31942841)) these question which are told some problems are present using Micromax mobiles at development on android apps. So i confused to buy mobile for testing? Please provide the solution...

Answer (score 0):

A Nexus device won't have any vendor-specific issues as you seem to have found. But just because it works on a Nexus, doesn't mean it will work on everything. So,  there really is no perfect single device for testing.